# Struts 2 getting an undefined number of select tags

Tags: struts2

I have a problem with select tags populated with objects from the class below :

```
public class Status {

private Person person;
private Date date;

private List<Requests> requestList;

 /*
      getters and setters
 */
}
```

The problem is that I generate an undefined number of these to show them in a table.
A select is populated with the list.

My question is : how to get all the results from the selects in the page and return them to the controller ?

Thank you in advance,

Steven P.

Comment: The framework is doing it automatically, so you don't need to do much more in the controller, but you can separate then on pieces and provide them one by one like a conveyer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** In your updateAction class (Where you want all the combobox results) create an array of String --> **private String[] myarray;**

```
public class UpdateUserAction extends ActionSupport {
    private String[] myarray;
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        //Print what we got from comboboxes
        for(String s: myarray)
        {
        System.out.println(s);  
        }
   }

//getter
//setters
public void setMyarray(String[] myarray) {
    this.myarray = myarray;
}

public String[] getMyarray() {
    return myarray;
}
}
```

**Step 2:** Give this name **myarray** in the name attribute of all combo boxes in jsp page in `<s:select name="myarray" />`.

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>  
<form action="update-user" method="post">
    <s:select name="myarray" id="ddlTown" list="{'option1','option2'}"/>
    <s:select name="myarray" id="ddlTown" list="{'option1','option2'}"/>
    <s:select name="myarray" id="ddlTown" list="{'option1','option2'}"/>
    <s:select name="myarray" id="ddlTown" list="{'option1','option2'}"/>
<s:submit/>
</form>
```

**Step 3:** You will get selections in this array now in update action where you got **String[] myarray**.

> option2
>   option1
>   option2
>   option1

Comment: I'll look into that.
The other problem i can have is the way I handle the List. I had to pass a map of map with the Status object to the JSP to make the table easily displayable but it's a pain to save data afterwards.

So I think I'll change the way i'm getting data and rewrite my save method
Thank you.